# Determining if these sets are compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Which of the following sets are compact?

(a) {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:2x^2-y^2\leq1$}

(b) {$x\in\mathbb{R}^n:2\leq||x||\leq4$}

(c) {$(e^{-x}\cos{x}, e^{-x}\sin{x}):x\geq0$} $\cup$ {$(x,0):0\leq x\leq1$}

(d) {$(e^{-x}\cos{\theta}, e^{-x}\sin{\theta}):x\geq0, 0\leq{\theta}\leq{2\pi}$}

---

I think,

(a) It is close and bounded because $2x^2-y^2$ can never be smaller than zero and defined to be smaller or equal to one. Thus {$0,1$}. By Heine-Borel theorem, it is closed and bounded, it is compact.

(b) Same approach. Also, if we draw a number line from 2 to 4, every point we find will form a ball also containing other points.

(c) By Borel-Lebesgue Theorem, this set follows "positive definitness", "symmetry" and "triangle inequality". It is a metric space. So it is compact.

(d) It is not a metric space. For example, $\sin{\pi} = \sin{0} = 0$, doesnt follow positive definitness. Not a metric space, not compact.

Please help!! thank you!!

Comment: Of course (d) is a metric space -- it is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, and a subset of a metric space is itself a metric space. The fact that $(1,0)$ is a member of the set for several different _reasons_ simultaneously doesn't mean that $(\cos 0,\sin 0)$ and $(\cos 2\pi,\sin 2\pi)$ are different elements. Both equal $(1,0)$, so they are the same element (and are therefore allowed to have zero distance)!

Comment: The first one isn't bounded, take $x$ arbitraryly large, and $y = \sqrt{2x^2}$, then $(x,y)$ is in the set, thus it can't be bounded.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of something that was asked just few days ago. Just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is not bounded,
(b) is compact with heine borell
(c) is compact use heine borell and take (0,0) in the left set to show it is the union of
2 compact sets.
(d) think if (0,0) is in the set, and if there is a sequence converging to (0,0)

Comment: would you please add some explanation on each part?